# Postgresql failed to start. Reboot is resetting the permission given to /var/run/postgresql/

Tags: postgresql

```
FATAL:  could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.1111.lock": Permission denied
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "S01B01" (10.10.222.193) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 1111?
```

Could you please help me in getting a permanent fix for this.

**postgresql.conf:**

```
data_directory = '/apps/ins/router/pgdata'

hba_file = '/apps/ins/router/pgdata/pg_hba.conf'
```

**pg_hba.conf:**

```
host     all             ins        10.10.10.10    255.255.255.255    trust
host     all             ins        127.0.0.1      255.255.255.255    trust
```

Comment: postgres should run as user:group postgres:postgres. The owner of /var/run/postgresql should also be postgres:postgres. Looks like you're trying to start this proces with wrong user.

Comment: The permission is postgres:postgres only for /var/run/postgresql directory. postgres is installed with ins user according to our application requirement. Don't know why reboot is changing the permission of /var/run/postgresql directory. As of now, I kept one crontab to change the permission every time on a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Both socket directories for PostgreSQL (`/run/postgresql` and `/var/run/postgresql`) are temporary directories created at boot time. (The `/var/run/postgresql` is in fact usually a symbolic link to `/run/postgresql`).

With the advent of systemd, a new mechanism called **systemd-tmpfiles** has been introduced to manage temporary files and directories.

Systemd-tmpfiles creates temporary directories during boot and sets their owner, group and permissions. It may read configuration files in three different locations. Files in `/etc/tmpfiles.d` override files with the same name in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d` and `/run/tmpfiles.d.`

Check those configuration directories for PostgreSQL configuration, usually `postgresql.conf`. (You will most likely find it at `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf`.) The file will contain something like the following line:

> `d /run/postgresql 0755 postgres postgres -`

You can change permissions, owner and group by editing that line. The recommended way to make such changes, however, is not to directly edit files under `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/`, but to copy configuration files over to `/etc/tmpfiles.d/`, and make the necessary changes in that copy instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix the issue is to relocate the PostgreSQL lock file location. We can do so by using below query

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET unix_socket_directories='<any-existing-path-with-valid-permissions>, /tmp';
```